# How to extend the facebook app access token that is going to be invalid very soon?

Tags: facebook, api, offline

We have business clients who use our apps to market their products. 
So every time new customers come we ask them to install our app. They follow Facebook standard procedures to install apps.

Our apps are based on server based authorization and cUrl. 
Our apps are based on offline_access functionality that is deprecated by Facebook and will expire very soon.

In this critical scenario I have some queries.

> > how to extend the Facebook app access token that is going to be invalid very soon?

I have already gone through this link https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/ and https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

But these links are seemed as more theoretical than practical. I am looking for some practical examples.

So far my understandings are:

> > I have to enable offline deprecation functionality from Facebook app dashboard
> >     Facebook will send me some notification before the access token going to be expired or invalid

The steps I will need to follow to extend the access token:

> > I have to get a short lived access token that will last for at most 2 hours and i can get more than one token in a day. 
> >     Then I have to use that short token to get the long lived access token for 60 days.

My questions are:

1. All of my above understandings are right (I am confused!)?
2. Do i have to re-generate the access token every 59 days after getting the reminder from Facebook? Isn't it back dated concept?!
3. Is there any easy automated way to extend the going to be expired access token or already expired access token?

Thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/ has all the information you need, you're operating under Scenario 2 in that document; existing offline_access tokens are still infinite until such time as the functionality is removed entirely, and otherwise tokens are valid for a maximum of 60 days.

Users must come back to your app at least once every 60 days in order for you to have a valid token for them - exceptions being the Ads API (infinite tokens) and Page Management APIs (infinite tokens)

The cutoff date for offline_access tokens was extended, but you shouldn't rely on the roadmap or blog for an update if you're already aware of the changes that need to be made in order to support the new token model

Comment: @lgy ...i have mentioned about this link above. But still not sure how to implement that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'implement' this - the standard [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) documentation explains how to implement auth in your app - if you're already using offline_access it's the same, except that you'll now have either 60 day tokens (no change needed) or get a short token which you need to exchange for a 60 day token, details for which are in the document